# Google Business Profile Performance API PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: google-my-business-api, google-my-business, google-business-profile-api, google-business-profile

I'm currently working on migrating from the Google My business V4.9 to the [Business Profile Performance API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/performance/rest)  .

For number of credentials the changes are working as expected but for others, there is a problem with making the request as I'm getting this error.

```
GET https://businessprofileperformance.googleapis.com/v1/locations/****:getDailyMetricsTimeSeries?dailyMetric=CALL_CLICKS&dailyRange.endDate.day=8&dailyRange.endDate.month=1&dailyRange.endDate.year=2023&dailyRange.startDate.day=31&dailyRange.startDate.month=12&dailyRange.startDate.year=2022
{
"code" : 403,
"errors" : [ {
"domain" : "global",
"message" : "The caller does not have permission",
"reason" : "forbidden"
} ],
"message" : "The caller does not have permission",
"status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

Worth to mention that for the same credentials and scope everything is working with the older endpoints.

I'm currently using https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage, can this be the problem as it has been deprecated(But you can still use it) and now there is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage instead?

**UPDATE**

It seems that before it simply returned an empty list of reports for this location, and now it's throwing an exception.

Comment: Did you enable the API? Do you have quota?

Comment: @vpriesner Yes, I did.
And I'm able to get data, but for specific locations I can't it seems like it's something in the permissions specifically for these locations. 
I've added an update to the question

Comment: Are you able to see insights for the affected locations via the GBP UI?

Comment: Are those locations live and appear on Google Maps (as compared to suspended locations)?

Comment: @vpriesner I am getting the same error, and the location appears on Google Map, in play ground I see this response {
  "error": {
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED", 
    "message": "The caller does not have permission", 
    "code": 403
  }
} . other locations of the same client have no problems.